# Detecting Window in an externel application has been changed?

Tags: python, image-processing, window

I'm currently writing a test automation application in python and I am stuck in finding a way to detect if the window in the target application has been changed (or moved to the next window in the application).

I did use the `win32gui.GetWindowText` function but it was not accurate, some time two window have the same name!

```
def windowTitle():
  tempWindowName=win32gui.GetWindowText(   win32gui.GetForegroundWindow() )
```

return  tempWindowName

Is there another way?

Comment: Can you please provide the code of what you have tried so far? :-)

Comment: Stating what you are wondering about is not the same as asking a question. Always include a question (as in a sentence with a question mark), for which the answer helps you (so no Yes/No answerable questions like: "Can someone help me?").

Comment: I'm searching for another way (image-processing , windows command ...) to identify a window and detect when it change .